# MSDeploy to Azure sites frequently fails despite retry switches

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, msdeploy

We do a lot of deploys to Azure using `msdeploy.exe` and pre-built packages. Intermittently, but fairly frequently, we're getting failures (apparently network issues).

The command is,

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
    -verb:sync -source:package=D:\packages\mysite.zip 
    -dest:auto,ComputerName=https://mysite-staging.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/msdeploy.axd?site=mysite__staging,UserName='$mysite__staging',Password='longpassword',AuthType='Basic'
    -retryAttempts:10
    -retryInterval:3000
    -setParam:name='foo1',value='bar1'
    -enableRule:AppOffline
    -setParam:name='foo2',value='bar2'
    -allowUntrusted=True
```

It usually works fine but then sometimes it'll fail with this message:

```
 Error Code: ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED
```

The `-retryAttempts` and `-retryInterval` options seem to have zero effect. The errors happened before I added them and now after adding them, there's no difference. No output from msdeploy saying it's retrying. **Is there something I'm missing in getting msdpeloy to retry?**

Everything, including the machine running the msdeploy, is hosted in the same region in Azure. There aren't any underlying network issues, especially not for 30,000 ms - either SCM/Kudu or msdeploy is failing on a higher layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, that issue sometimes occurred because of the Fiddler and (more often) because of the slow Internet.

Also, you may try to use Kudu commands like the extension of the msdeploy and SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT which you may set => web app settings => app settings => add the setting with the needed value (to say 360 (in seconds)). [Reference](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings). It says that any external command will be killed after some time, so maybe it can be related.

Answer (score 1):

I have also had this issue and have posted a question to MS internally on this.

One trick that I have is to "warmup" the site prior to running msdeploy.  This can be as simple as a powershell command to invoke a webrequest on the site URL.  For some reason, this reduces the number of connection termination errors.